# How can we pass an attribute from child to parent?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I am trying to pass a list from child to parent.
Here I am expecting class `IVone92c` should pass its attribute `candidateList` to `IVone83c` and it should should get the same in its own list. Instead the object gets appended in IVone92c's `candidateList`. Why does this happen? How can I achieve my desired output?

```
class IVone83c(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.candidateList = list()

    def resolve(self, SabxarUpa, candiList):
        self.candidateList.extend(candiList)


class IVone92c(IVone83c):

    def check(self,SabxarUpa, rule=None):
            self.candidateList = [IVone92]
             super(IVone92c, self).resolve(SabxarUpa, self.candidateList)
```

Comment: So you **want** the data shared between the instances of different classes? Then you should have a *class attribute*, not an *instance attribute*, in the parent class.

Comment: Perhaps you should first correct all the errors in your code?

Comment: @7stud - this is more like a pseudoe code, which I have put here to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

```
class IVone83c(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.candidateList = ['goodbye']

    def resolve(self, SabxarUpa, candiList):
        print self.candidateList
        print self


class IVone92c(IVone83c):

    def check(self,SabxarUpa, rule=None):
        self.candidateList = [IVone92c]
        super(IVone92c, self).resolve(SabxarUpa, self.candidateList)

iv92 = IVone92c()
print iv92

--output:--
<__main__.IVone92c object at 0x2bdc30>  #<--Note the id
[<class '__main__.IVone92c'>]
<__main__.IVone92c object at 0x2bdc30>  #<--Note the id
```

> **super(type[, object-or-type])**
>
> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent...
>
> If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is
>   unbound.

Conversely, if the second argument is provided, the super object is *bound* to the second argument.  The second argument in your super() call is an `IVone92c_instance`.  *Bound* means that super() passes the `IVone92c_instance`  as the first argument to the parent method, which means the `IVone92c_instance` is assigned to the self parameter variable in the parent method, which means that inside the parent method self is the `IVone92c_instance`.

> How can I achieve my desired output?

It's not clear what your desired output is.  You say:

> Here I am expecting class IVone92c should pass its attribute
>   candidateList to IVone83c

But of course, that makes no sense.  You want to pass a list to a class?  What does that mean?  What do you expect to happen?   As jonrsharpe mentioned in the comment, you can store data in a class attribute.  Is that what you want to do?

Or, do you somehow want to create an instance of the parent class, then update its list, then have the parent instance miraculously survive until you are ready to retrieve it?

```
class IVone83c(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.candidateList = ['goodbye']

    def resolve(self, SabxarUpa, candiList):
        #print(self.candidateList)
        print(self)
        self.candidateList.extend(candiList)


class IVone92c(IVone83c):

    def check(self,SabxarUpa, rule=None):
        self.candidateList = [IVone92c]
        iv83 = IVone83c()
        iv83.candidateList.extend(self.candidateList)
        self.candidateList = iv83.candidateList[:]
        print iv83.candidateList
        print self.candidateList
        #Where do you want to save iv83?

iv92 = IVone92c()
iv92.check('hello')

--output:--
['goodbye', <class '__main__.IVone92c'>]
['goodbye', <class '__main__.IVone92c'>]
```